# Minecraft Forge Mod Loader (FML) Loading and crashing MC

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

I'm new to Minecraft Coding and Forge. I'm repeatedly getting this error that FML (Forge Mod Loader) is loading causing errors. I have FML for 1.12.2 MC and Forge Version 1.12.2-14.23.5.2854
I also tried Forge version 1.12.2-14.23.5.2855, but the same errors were thrown.
I am using JRE 1.8.0_251.
My IDE is Eclipse 2020-12

And when I do "runClient.launch" which launches Minecraft Client 1.12.2, it shows Constructing Mods, but when it comes to 3rd step, then bam! It crashes
In preferences Tab in eclipse, I have selected the Correct JRE.
Pls help me regarding this issue.

JVM Args
`-Xmx2G`

Error Log -

```
 Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from Forge Mod Loader (FML)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry.newChannel(NetworkRegistry.java:207)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.internal.FMLNetworkHandler.registerChannel(FMLNetworkHandler.java:185)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLContainer.modConstruction(FMLContainer.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:219)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:136)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:595)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:232)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:467)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 125114560 bytes (119 MB) / 378011648 bytes (360 MB) up to 935854080 bytes (892 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2854 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

    | State | ID         | Version      | Source                                                      | Signature |
    |:----- |:---------- |:------------ |:----------------------------------------------------------- |:--------- |
    | LC    | minecraft  | 1.12.2       | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
    | LC    | mcp        | 9.42         | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
    | LE    | FML        | 8.0.99.99    | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
    | L     | forge      | 14.23.5.2854 | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
    | L     | examplemod | 1.0          | main                                                        | None      |

    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel' Version: '3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.4229' Renderer: 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000'
[16:30:21] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:553]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# D:\1.12.2\run\.\crash-reports\crash-2021-07-14_16.30.21-client.txt
```

Comment: The solution was to use any version higher than 1.12.2. 1.16.5 worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE: This fix may not be a permanent or good solution to the problem but I have found it to fix mine so try at your own risk.**

With no mention of what version of ForgeGradle you are using, I will have to assume that it is version 3.0 or higher.

For anyone experiencing the same issue for ForgeGradle version 5.1.73 or higher, using Forge version 1.12.2-14.23.5.2860 the following worked for me:

### Solution

#### Solution 1 - Remove MergeTool

**NOTE: I previously tried this method but it stopped working suddenly. If that happens to you, I suggest trying solution 2 or some of the other answers on this question such as clearing the Gradle cache or running a clean build.**

Add the following into the `configuration` block in your `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations.configureEach {
    exclude group: "net.minecraftforge", module: "mergetool"
}
```

This will remove the `mergetool` dependency which seems to be causing issues.

#### Solution 2 - Switch to a version of MergeTool that doesn't contain the BUKKIT entry

Add the following to the bottom of your `dependencies` block:

```
implementation ("net.minecraftforge:mergetool:0.2.3.3") { force = true }
```

This will force Gradle to use [this particular version of MergeTool](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MergeTool/tree/0.2.3)

#### Solution 3 - Removing IDEA blocks and switching build mode to Gradle

Some may have used this old solution to fix IntelliJ not copying resources properly with Gradle. The new solution is to add this block to your `build.gradle`:

```
legacy {
    fixClasspath = true
}
```

So you must now remove the following from the top of your `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = true
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```

And you must also switch to building with Gradle:

1. Go to `File` > `Settings...` (Or, Ctrl + Alt + S) > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Gradle`
2. Select your project in the list on the left pane
3. Change both `Build and run using:` and `Run tests using:` to `Gradle`
4. Save (Click OK)

### Explanation

According to [Issue #748 on MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle by tie](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle/issues/748), there seems to be an issue where the MergeTool dependency loads first before FML properly does, so `Side` is overwritten with a version which contains a `BUKKIT` entry which FML does not expect. (Normally, it only contains `SERVER` and `CLIENT` and only instantiates channels for the two)

I have not experienced any issues with removing this dependency *yet*, however if I find anything I will mention it here in the future.

### Confirmation

I have tested this on Windows 10 build 21H2 19044.2728, with Gradle version 7.4.2, ForgeGradle version 5.1.73, Forge version 1.12.2-14.23.5.2860, Mappings channel "stable" version 39-1.12

### Issues

- [SOLUTION 1] For some strange reason, this isn't working anymore. I have no idea *how*, but somehow `Side` is gaining a `BUKKIT` enum entry immaculately. I will research this further and inspect why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to figure out how to solve this. Based of off my research, you delete the `.gradle` folder in your home dir, or you reload gradle.

Comment: I tried that first. Didn't solve my problem. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @JustInCoding I'm sure this is fg being bad, so like reimport project, delete build/

Comment: Yeah I have re-imported this project many times. But still. Do you think that the problem is with Forge version or FML version?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error as you when I did "runClient" (The only difference is that I use IDEA). I found that the directory name may be the reason of the error.My directory name is "1.12.2".I tried to change it to "mod" and rebuild gradle. After that ,the "runClient" can run normally.

Comment: For some reason, changing the name of the project indeed fixed the bug for me as you said. Does anyone know why this fixes it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on forge 1.12.2 with my new laptop.

UPDATE :

The solution wasn't remove the mergetool. You need to keep it. Then, you click on this button (download button) to download sources and it should be good.

https://imgur.com/M2UjoSG