# Default forge mod crashes on start and doesn't seem to build right

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

When I start the default forge 1.12.2 Minecraft mod using [runClient] in IntelliJ I get this crash:

```
Time: 7/12/23 9:43 PM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from Forge Mod Loader (FML)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry.newChannel(NetworkRegistry.java:207)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.internal.FMLNetworkHandler.registerChannel(FMLNetworkHandler.java:185)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLContainer.modConstruction(FMLContainer.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:219)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:136)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:595)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:232)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:467)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_382, IBM Corporation
    Java VM Version: Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20230608_693 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 936ec5450
OMR      - 0e572348b
JCL      - 1a75d66cae based on jdk8u382-b03), Eclipse OpenJ9
    Memory: 14693528 bytes (14 MB) / 135135232 bytes (128 MB) up to 4280090624 bytes (4081 MB)
    JVM Flags: 4 total; -Xoptionsfile=C:\Users\gmans\.jdks\semeru-1.8.0_382\jre\bin\default\options.default -Xlockword:mode=default,noLockword=java/lang/String,noLockword=java/util/MapEntry,noLockword=java/util/HashMap$Entry,noLockword=org/apache/harmony/luni/util/ModifiedMap$Entry,noLockword=java/util/Hashtable$Entry,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodType,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/CollectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConstructorHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConvertHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ArgumentConversionHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/AsTypeHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ExplicitCastHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FilterReturnHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/DirectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ReceiverBoundHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/DynamicInvokerHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldGetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldSetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/StaticFieldGetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/StaticFieldSetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/IndirectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InterfaceHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/VirtualHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/PrimitiveHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InvokeExactHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InvokeGenericHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/VarargsCollectorHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ThunkTuple -XX:+EnsureHashed:java/lang/Class,java/lang/Thread -Xjcl:jclse29
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2859 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

    | State | ID         | Version      | Source                                                      | Signature |
    |:----- |:---------- |:------------ |:----------------------------------------------------------- |:--------- |
    | LC    | minecraft  | 1.12.2       | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
    | LC    | mcp        | 9.42         | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
    | LE    | FML        | 8.0.99.99    | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
    | L     | forge      | 14.23.5.2859 | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
    | L     | examplemod | 1.0          | main                                                        | None      |

    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation' Version: '4.6.0 NVIDIA 419.72' Renderer: 'Quadro K2100M/PCIe/SSE2'
[21:43:17] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:553]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\gmans\Desktop\Java\ahhhwhynowork\run\.\crash-reports\crash-2023-07-12_21.43.17-client.txt

> Task :runClient FAILED
```

I know this is very similar to [Minecraft Forge Mod Loader (FML) Loading and crashing MC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377027/minecraft-forge-mod-loader-fml-loading-and-crashing-mc) but I have tried their solutions and they have not worked. There also seems to be problems importing it when I first load it (when the external sources are appearing).

I get this error:

```
> Configure project :
New Dep: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2859_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s

  Failed to apply patch: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2859:userdev3: patches/net/minecraft/crash/CrashReportCategory.java
    Hunk #1 Failed: Cannot find hunk target
Error getting artifact: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2859_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12:sources@jar from  MinecraftUserRepo
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to apply patches to source file, see log for details: C:\Users\gmans\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\minecraft_user_repo\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.12.2-14.23.5.2859\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859-decomp.jar
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.userdev.MinecraftUserRepo.findPatched(MinecraftUserRepo.java:1071)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.userdev.MinecraftUserRepo.findSource(MinecraftUserRepo.java:1107)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.userdev.MinecraftUserRepo.findFile(MinecraftUserRepo.java:411)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.BaseRepo.getArtifact(BaseRepo.java:81)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.BaseRepo.getArtifact(BaseRepo.java:41)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.BaseRepo$Builder$1.lambda$getArtifact$0(BaseRepo.java:127)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1361)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:514)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:501)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:487)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.BaseRepo$Builder$1.getArtifact(BaseRepo.java:127)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.BaseRepo$Builder$1.getArtifact(BaseRepo.java:124)
    at com.amadornes.artifactural.base.repository.ArtifactProviderBuilder$Complete.getArtifact(ArtifactProviderBuilder.java:92)
    at com.amadornes.artifactural.base.repository.SimpleRepository.getArtifact(SimpleRepository.java:41)
    at com.amadornes.artifactural.gradle.GradleRepositoryAdapter$GeneratingFileResourceRepository.findArtifact(GradleRepositoryAdapter.java:298)
    at com.amadornes.artifactural.gradle.GradleRepositoryAdapter$GeneratingFileResourceRepository.resource(GradleRepositoryAdapter.java:277)
    at com.amadornes.artifactural.gradle.GradleRepositoryAdapter$GeneratingFileResourceRepository.resource(GradleRepositoryAdapter.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.staticResourceExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.artifactExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.findOptionalArtifacts(ExternalResourceResolver.java:260)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver$MavenRemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveSourceArtifacts(MavenResolver.java:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver$MavenRemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveSourceArtifacts(MavenResolver.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$AbstractRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(ExternalResourceResolver.java:380)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(ExternalResourceResolver.java:450)
    at com.amadornes.artifactural.gradle.GradleRepositoryAdapter$1$1.resolveArtifactsWithType(GradleRepositoryAdapter.java:202)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:402)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LocalModuleComponentRepository$LocalAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(LocalModuleComponentRepository.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:153)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifactsWithType(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolveArtifactsWithType(ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.addArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.buildComponentResult(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:168)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.createResult(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.execute(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:133)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.IdeDependencySet$IdeDependencyResult.resolveAuxiliaryArtifacts(IdeDependencySet.java:161)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.IdeDependencySet$IdeDependencyResult.visit(IdeDependencySet.java:90)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.IdeDependencySet.visit(IdeDependencySet.java:71)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.internal.IdeaDependenciesProvider.visitDependencies(IdeaDependenciesProvider.java:105)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.internal.IdeaDependenciesProvider.getDependencies(IdeaDependenciesProvider.java:90)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.internal.IdeaDependenciesProvider.provide(IdeaDependenciesProvider.java:66)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.resolveDependencies(IdeaModule.java:589)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildDependencies(IdeaModelBuilder.java:125)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.build(IdeaModelBuilder.java:112)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildAll(IdeaModelBuilder.java:78)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildAll(IdeaModelBuilder.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.findModel(ProjectImportAction.java:557)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ModelConverter.populateModuleBuildDirs(ModelConverter.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.<init>(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:55)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:334)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.runAction(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:109)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.access$000(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$1.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$1.buildFinished(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:370)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:327)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:162)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:147)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:826)
```

This may be unrelated to it crashing but I figured it might be worth putting here in case it's useful:

I tried the solutions at [Minecraft Forge Mod Loader (FML) Loading and crashing MC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377027/minecraft-forge-mod-loader-fml-loading-and-crashing-mc), but they did not help. I tried different open jdks, which still didn't work. I've deleted and redownloaded the forge mdk still did not work. I heard that different versions might work, but I want to keep 1.12.2. The weird thing is that it was working fine on my other computer which was not a struggle to get it working however I can't use it at the moment.