intellij runClient error minecraft forge 1.12.2
I have a problem when I try run the task runClient. My launcher minecraft start, but after crashed.
Below follow the error:
net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from Forge Mod Loader (FML)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry.newChannel(NetworkRegistry.java:207)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.internal.FMLNetworkHandler.registerChannel(FMLNetworkHandler.java:185)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLContainer.modConstruction(FMLContainer.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:219)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
        at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:136)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:595)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:232)
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:467)
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
        at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:123)   
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
        at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
        Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
        Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
        Java Version: 1.8.0_202, Oracle Corporation
        Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
        Memory: 398984336 bytes (380 MB) / 1006108672 bytes (959 MB) up to 3793747968 bytes (3618 MB)
        JVM Flags: 0 total;
        IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
        FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2860 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
        States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

        | State | ID        | Version      | Source                                                      | Signature |
        |:----- |:--------- |:------------ |:----------------------------------------------------------- |:--------- |
        | LC    | minecraft | 1.12.2       | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
        | LC    | mcp       | 9.42         | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
        | LE    | FML       | 8.0.99.99    | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
        | L     | forge     | 14.23.5.2860 | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
        | L     | slmj      | 0.0.1        | main                                                        | None      |

        Loaded coremods (and transformers):
        GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel' Version: '4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.2127' Renderer: 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 630'
[21:20:25] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:553]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\alber\OneDrive\┴rea de Trabalho\Slmod\run\.\crash-reports\crash-2024-04-19_21.
20.25-client.txt

I tried to reinstall the project from 0 and run it without any code just the basics for a first operation, however I was unsuccessful.

similar ask here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377027/minecraft-forge-mod-loader-fml-loading-and-crashing-mc

Does this answer your question? Minecraft Forge Mod Loader (FML) Loading and crashing MC
